# Expectation, variance etc for uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, uniform-distribution

Suppose $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$

Now I have to calculate

1. expectation
2. variance
3. distribution function
4. density

of $U^5$

They gave me a hint to use the transformation rule for expectation which is

$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)]=\int_l^rh(a)f(a)da$$
X is a random variable and $h:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and we have  $[l,r]$

But how can I use this rule to calculate the expectation without having the density  $f(a)da$?

My approach was to calculate the density first.

$$U\sim unif[0,2]$$
$$X:=U^5$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X\le x) = \mathbb{P}=\left(U\le \sqrt[5]{x}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^5}}=\int_o^xf(a)da, \ (0\le x\le32)$$
$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{4}{25}\frac{1}{\sqrt[9]{x^5}},  & \text{$0\le x \le 32$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Will be this the correct approach or will there be a easier way? I am stuck at this point

Comment: You seem to think that $P\left(U\leq\sqrt[5]{x}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^{5}}}$. That is not the case: $P(U\leq u)=\frac12u$ if $0\leq u\leq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

First if $supp(U)=[0,2]$, then $supp(U^5)=[0,2^5]$

**1. Expectation**

The hint is correct and enough to compute the expectation of $U^5$.

$$\mathbb{E}[U^5]=\int_0^2u^5p_U(u)du,$$
where $p_U(u)$ is the pdf of $U$.

Hence,

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[U^5] &=\int_0^2u^5\dfrac{1}{2}du\\
&=\dfrac{16}{3}
\end{align}$$

**2. Variance**
$$\begin{align}
Var(U^5) &= \mathbb{E}[U^{10}]-(\mathbb{E}[U^5])^2\\
&=\dfrac{6400}{99}
\end{align}$$

**3. CDF**
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(U^5\leq u) &= \mathbb{P}(U \leq u^{1/5})\\
&=\int_0^{u^{1/5}}\dfrac{1}{2}du\\
&=\dfrac{u^{1/5}}{2}
\end{align}$$

**4. PDF**
\begin{align}
p_{U^5}(u) &= \dfrac{d\mathbb{P}(U^5\leq u)}{du}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{10}u^{-4/5}
\end{align}

Comment: The first line of this answer is not true and contradicts the rest of the answer.

Comment: @drhab what is (not) true?

Comment: It is not true that $U^5$ has uniform distribution if $U$ has uniform distribution. If it would then e.g. its PDF would be constant on $(0,32)$ which contradicts  your result mentioned in 4.

Comment: I agree with you, even in 3. it is not the cdf of a uniform distribution. Thank you

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have question for the expectation, you write  $p_u(u)$ for the density of $U^5$ and then in the next line you get $\frac{1}{2}$ Where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?

Comment: Alright I got it. We have $[a,b]$ with $[0,2]$ and for the density we have $\frac{1}{b-a}$ therefore it is $\frac{1}{2-0}=\frac{1}{2}$